# Use object keys to divide javascript array of objects into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```
const array = [ 
{ year: 1971, temp1: 9.5, temp2: 8.0, temp3: 9.5 },
{ year: 1972, temp1: 15.0, temp2: 3.7, temp3: 94.3 },
...
{ year: 1999, temp1: 12.0, temp2: 31.0, temp3: 24.0 }
];
```

How might I divide this array into three arrays with the following key-value pairs (all objects having the 'year' key-value pair but different 'temp' pairs for each array):

```
const array1 = [ { year: 1971, temp1: 9.5}, { year: 1972, temp1: 15.0 } ... { year: 1999, temp1: 12.0 } ];

const array2 = [ { year: 1971, temp2: 8.0}, { year: 1972, temp2: 3.7 } ... { year: 1999, temp2: 31.0 } ];

const array3 = [ { year: 1971, temp3: 9.5}, { year: 1972, temp3: 94.3 } ... { year: 1999, temp3: 24.0  } ];
```

EDIT: I've been attempting this by trying to loop through both the Object.keys as well as the rows of the array but everything I've come up with involves looping through the entire array multiple times.

Comment: "write this code for me" is not usually the way to ask questions on SO.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave posters the benefit of the doubt. I did spent quite a bit of time working on a solution before posting. It would take the same amount of time and space to ask what I've tried instead of jumping to the conclusion that I wanted someone to "write this code for me".

Comment: The way it's presented is "write this code for me". It would very much matter *what* you tried and why it didn't work in order to suggest either an improvement or a better solution. It's a bad question because it doesn't include that information. If it's not there then it doesn't really matter if you've spent 2 minutes or 2 days on this without telling anybody. Regarding your edit: if it wasn't for that information, I'd have honestly given you a solution that loops multiple times through the array. So, not what you want and what you already tried. That's why the information matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and while iterating over the [object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on each step of the reduce, you decide on which array to put a new generated object with the format `{year, temp}`:

```js
const array = [ 
  {year: 1971, temp1: 9.5, temp2: 8.0, temp3: 9.5},
  {year: 1972, temp1: 15.0, temp2: 3.7, temp3: 94.3},
  {year: 1999, temp1: 12.0, temp2: 31.0, temp3: 24.0}
];

let res = array.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    Object.keys(curr).forEach((k, j) =>
    {
        if (j > 0)
        {
            acc[j - 1] = acc[j - 1] || [];
            acc[j - 1].push({year: curr.year, [k]: curr[k]});
        }
    });

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Elegant solution.